# PointField does not become Point but Geometry

Tags: django, postgresql, gis, postgis

I am using a PointField:

```
class Location(AbstractBase):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    level = models.IntegerField()
    gps = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True, srid=4326)
```

However, when it is generated in postgresql, it becomes a GEOMETRY field. Why not data type "Point"? That one exists in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoDjango supports the PostGIS data types, not the native PostgreSQL geometric data types.